# get more than five results from google map AutoComplete API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

i am using this API to search location from google map API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete

when i search for place it gives only five results. Can you please tell me that what will be the way to get more than five results i mean complete results. if you know some other API to search multiple location please tell me. Thanks

like i am using following path to search but it gives only five results

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=filadelfia&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBPkN4zhGuTqm58_nHVKWWM9MZwYrz09FU

Answer (score 2):

Per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete:

> An XML response consists of a single  element with two types of
> child elements:
>
> - A single  element contains metadata on the request. See Status Codes below.
> - Zero of more  elements, each containing information about
>   a single Place. See Place Autocomplete Results for information about
>   these results. The Places API returns up to 5 results.